# Ошибка при вставке в таблицу

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Допустим имеется таблица с 50 колонками. При вставке ошибка - неверное число, в колонку с числовым типом вставляется строка.
Можно ли стандартными средствами узнать в какую именно колонку вставляется некорректное значение?
В dbms_output exception показать может или в лог записать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью `dbms_errlog`.

1. Один раз выполняем скрипт:

   ```
   begin
     dbms_errlog.create_error_log('mytable');
   end;
   /
   ```

   Будет создана таблица `err$_mytable`.
2. Пишем `INSERT` с дополнительным разделом:

   ```
   insert into mytable (...)
   values (...)
   log errors into err$_mytable reject limit unlimited;
   ```
3. После выполнения вставки (при условии `reject limit unlimited` исключений не будет никогда, так что надо проверять таблицу с логами) смотрим, что не так:

   ```
   select * from err$_mytable;
   ```

   В таблицу логов попадут все строки, в которых возникла ошибка. Там же будут два дополнительных столбца, в которых будет код ошибки и расшифровка. Столбец вы, правда, не узнаете, но хотя бы увидите, какие данные вставляются (особенно полезно в случае `insert ... select ...` или `MERGE`), и сможете понять, что не так.

Работает также с `UPDATE` и `MERGE`.

См. также в документации: [error_logging_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#BGBDIGAH), [dbms_errlog](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_errlog.htm#ARPLS680).

P. S. Ну а вообще, конечно, совет от Кэпа: не вставляйте строку в числовое поле ;)